# Call mediator without error timeout

Tags: wso2, timeout, call, mediator, vfs

I have call mediator with VFS inside to create file. When the saving is failed (no permission) I don't receive timeout error or something else to understand that. That is  part from the in sequence:
`<property description="Concat path"
                   expression="fn:concat('vfs:file:///',get-property('BPath'),'/',get-property('dynamic'),'/wso2.file')"
                   name="Path"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <header expression="get-property('Path')" name="To" scope="default"/>
         <property description="OUT_ONLY=true"
                   name="OUT_ONLY"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"
                   value="true"/>
         <call description="">
            <endpoint>
               <default/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>`

The question is: how to get error message from the call mediator when saving is failed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating fault sequences or error handlers?

You can add a fault sequence for proxy service:

```
<faultSequence>
        <sequence key="conf:sequences/common/ErrorHandlerSeq.xml"/>
</faultSequence>
```

Or, to define error handler for the sequence:

```
<sequence name="mySequence" onError="conf:sequences/common/ErrorHandlerSeq.xml">
 ...
</sequence>
```

However, error handling in wso2 is a bit special, your mediator might need to wrap an exception into SynapseException, to get it trigger the error handler.

**UPDATE**

Following the comment, it looks to be a well-known problem with error handling in WSO2. The culprit is ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.class from synapse-core, having the following lines:

```
/*     */     catch (SynapseException syne)
/*     */     {
/* 193 */       if (!synCtx.getFaultStack().isEmpty()) {
/* 194 */         warn(traceOn, "Executing fault handler due to exception encountered", synCtx);
/* 195 */         ((FaultHandler)synCtx.getFaultStack().pop()).handleFault(synCtx, syne);
/*     */       }
/*     */       else {
/* 198 */         warn(traceOn, "Exception encountered but no fault handler found - message dropped", synCtx);
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     finally {
/* 202 */       StatisticsReporter.endReportForAllOnRequestProcessed(synCtx);
/*     */     }
```

The obvious problem here is triggering error handlers only when SynapseException is caught, the others are simply ignored.

If you have a posibility to update classes of your WSO2 instance, you can make it catching all exceptions.

I changed this piece of code with the following:

```
/*     */     catch (Exception syne)
/*     */     {
/* 193 */       log.error("Exception caught on mediation sequence", syne);
            if (!synCtx.getFaultStack().isEmpty()) {
/* 194 */         warn(traceOn, "Executing fault handler due to exception encountered", synCtx);
              try {
/* 195 */           ((FaultHandler)synCtx.getFaultStack().pop()).handleFault(synCtx, syne);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  log.error("Exception caught while executing fault handler", ex);
                  //warn(traceOn, "Exception caught while executing fault handler", synCtx);
                  if (!synCtx.getFaultStack().isEmpty()) {
                      warn(traceOn, "Executing nested fault handler", synCtx);
                      try {
                          ((FaultHandler)synCtx.getFaultStack().pop()).handleFault(synCtx, ex);
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          log.error("Exception caught while executing nested fault handler, mediation stopped", e);
                      }
                  } else {
                      warn(traceOn, "No nested fault handler found - message dropped", synCtx);
                  }
              }
/*     */       }
/*     */       else {
/* 198 */         warn(traceOn, "Exception encountered but no fault handler found - message dropped", synCtx);
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
```

It allows to use even nested error handlers, which is not working out of box, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, i have a fault sequence (tried both variants) but in this situation it is not running. The proxy return blank result (<missing raw response data>)